# What is the best way to store secure static data which can be easily updated by clients?

Tags: database-design, static

I'm currently building an education website which contains a lot of content such as questions, videos and notes which all need to be securely locked away and exposed to users with relevant permissions.

Now one thing I'm stuck on is how to implement a way to store all the course data, questions and videos.

I believe I have videos down pat; I'm going to use Cloudflare to store the videos securely and serve them to the user. But for everything else I'm not sure if I'm following an antipattern.

Currently, I plan to store the questions and course outlines as json files which are stored on my express server. Then on the server's boot, I search the folder and store all the question/note json paths to a JS Object which I treat as an index.

Then when a user wants something I authenticate them, then send the relevant json files they need using the index. I also will be storing cloudflare video ID's to help organize my videos into course structures using JSON. Some questions may have images and such as well, where I create a time-limited URL for the user to access with, sending it with the JSON.

While it seems good in theory, I have no idea if this is a good approach to take.

Will it be fast? 
Scalable?

It just seems weird I'm not using a Database like what I'm using to store user data. Folders seem the easiest while also allowing my team to add more questions or notes whenever.

Is this the best approach to take or is there something better I can do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have something "static, but changeable." Clearly you have a need to update questions and course data. You also have a need to keep arbitrary users from making these updates. This concept is called **authorization**.

Each user, depending on the role they play in the system, should be capable of some number of actions. Students should be able to read questions, and take notes. Instructors should be able to create, read, update and delete questions. This logic belongs in application code. The authorization code should read which capabilities the user has, and deny access when appropriate. This denial of access can take the form of simply omitting an edit icon from the user interface up to a big, fat, red "Permission Denied!" screen when the user attempts to perform a forbidden action.

Your choice to use JSON files to store data is neither an anti-pattern, nor a best practice. Storing data as JSON is fine. Given the proper file permissions you could allow end users to update these files. The code to implement this behavior is not too complicated — unless of course you want to allow multiple people to change the same files at the same time. Now you must deal with concurrency issues. Your JSON file storage technique will break down quickly. This is where SQL and No-SQL databases shine. They figured out that whole "concurrency thing" quite a while ago.

A JSON file is not inherently insecure. A database is not inherently secure. You need to set up access rules for data regardless of storage technology. Databases can give you fine grained control over basic reads and data manipulation statements. You will likely need additional constraints programmed in to your application above and beyond the constraints offered to you by the database or file storage.

I wish this next bit could be tattooed on every software engineer: **data security is not just determined by your choice of data storage technology.** Data storage provides its own security and constraints, but your application's need for security will very well require additional checks outside of data storage.

Choose data storage based on your needs for storing and retrieving data. Most solutions will offer a plethora of security features. Program the other constraints in your application when the data storage technology doesn't offer a solution that fits your needs. It is pretty easy for databases to prevent users from UPDATE-ing using SQL. It's nigh impossible for the database to hide the edit icon in the user interface.